# Laravel how to convert minutes to days in blade?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a simple output from controller to blade:

```
{{ $BanInfo->banlength }}
```

It shows minutes. How can i convert ONLY TO DAYS? And i need to use only in blade. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-format-a-carbon-date-inside-blade?page=1)?

Comment: It's definitely the ugly way to do it, but using Carbon date formatter will be the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply can Division to 1440 to get days

```
{{ round($BanInfo->banlength / 1440) }}
```

Comment: Thanks! U really helped me out :)